How to empty the hard drive to test disaster recovery?
Suppose I have a full TimeMachine backup of a newly installed and configured Mac OS. No important data yet.
I want to test disaster recovery from the scenario of total physical loss. I don't want to destroy the Mac for real and get a new one, so I need to emulate the situation that the Mac is now the replacement with an empty hard drive.
How to do that?
About 10 years ago I would just do something like:
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0 count=128 bs=1M

On modern, cutting-edge Macs, however, I am not even sure if that will work (maybe there are some belts & braces against doing it even for root, or maybe it will not actually wipe the data on the very underlying physical drive, I don't know).
The disks look this:
sudo diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         494.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +494.4 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.3 GB    disk3s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 10.3 GB    disk3s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 5.4 GB     disk3s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                939.8 MB   disk3s3
   5:                APFS Volume Data                    30.0 GB    disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk3s6

So, how to wipe my Mac to test disaster recovery?

"sudo dd if=/dev/zero ..." - Please note there's no point in using dd where a simple cat will do.

@marcelm dd allows to set the amount of data to be written. How a simple cat can do it?

Hah, I had a bit of a knee-jerk reaction when I saw dd, which is often-repeated advice for imaging or erasing entire drives where plain cat would be better. You're right, if you want control over the amount of data written, dd is appropriate.

Sorry if I'm missing the point and why would you not emulate the situation in which the Mac is the replacement with an empty hard drive and there is no important data by plugging in a new, blank HD, which should cost roughly pocket change?
How could any other method not depend on devilish detail?

@RobbieGoodwin Why juggle hardware if the existing one can be brought to pristine original state just by issuing some commands? I'm not even sure if it's technically possible to replace HDD on modern MacBook Airs without replacing the whole board, and even if it is, why bother?

If modern MacBook Airs matter here, why not specify them in the OQ? (Google, for one, thinks you can buy fresh SSD for modern MacBook Airs)
The reason to juggle hardware is that when you ask 'if' the existing one can be brought to pristine original state just by issuing some commands, 'if' is the operative term.
Are you now suggesting the sole purpose of the OQ was to Ask for the command list?

@RobbieGoodwin Are modern MacBook Airs in your view not a subset of all "modern, cutting-edge Macs"? Or do you reserve the word "Mac" only for stationary desktop ones? The word "emulate" IMO should have been indicative that hardware solutions are excluded, so yes, the sole purpose of the question is to find out what commands (either terminal or rich UI) can do it.

If you want to talk about a subset, talk about the subset and please don't ask anyone to believe a subset can generally represent the main set…
Your choice, Greendrake: Modern MacBook Airs or 'all modern, cutting-edge Macs'? You presumably  had a reason for introducing 'modern MacBook Airs' and now you seem to want to drop that in favour of 'all modern, cutting-edge Macs'.

@RobbieGoodwin I surely had a reason to mention "modern, cutting-edge Macs" but that had nothing to do with hardware. It's software — specifically how modern MacOS presumably makes it hard to wipe the hard drive at the low level even with root privileges. In this regard, MacBook Airs do represent the main set because whether it is an Air or a desktop makes no difference. Don't forget that the word "emulate" should have excluded any thought of a hardware solution.

I don't insist you consider hardware. I do suggest that unless there's a good reason not to - including fear of fumbling fingers - hardware is more likely to give a yes-or-no answer, and that more quickly.
Almost separately if you want to talk about a sub-set, talk about a sub-set. If you want to specify a property as common to all sub-sets, specify it before citing it. If you want to 'presume' anything, justify your presumption… including that the word 'emulate' has only your cited meaning, even without different circumstances.

@RobbieGoodwin Thanks for your instructions, but I don't need them. I talk about what I want to talk about, and justify things only if I think I need to. Have a nice day.

God luck with your quest.


I need to emulate the situation that the Mac is now the replacement with an empty hard drive.

A replacement Mac (or a new logic board) will have the drive configured as you now have it. So all you need to do is just restore your data.
I would strongly advise against any kind of low-level wipe of the entire device.
That will delete the Recovery Partition, also firmware, and things like security tokens. Erasing the device may 'brick' your Mac, and you will have to connect a second, working Mac to it, and use Apple's Configurator app to restore the OS and firmware.
Also, note that TM doesn't backup the OS. The OS and user data are held on separate volumes. This means that all user data can be wiped from (and restored to) the "Data" volume, without affecting the OS volume or any other volumes.
Re: "total physical loss". The SSD is now a part of the logic board. Any 'disaster' to the SSD hardware will require a new board.
You can return a Mac to a 'factory' state by using "Erase All Content and Settings" in System Settings > Transfer or Reset.

Okay, so how to wipe the Data volume? dd?

benwiggy:  According to everymac.com, the Mac Studio models do have a replaceable SDD.

For disaster recovery, I would want a bootable USB, hard copy of the instructions for an erase install and your local backup on two external hard drives.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/101578
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/erase-your-mac-mchl7676b710/mac
https://support.apple.com/en-us/102664

Since modern macOS implementations encrypt the data at rest, you don’t need to mess with overwriting the storage, when you discard the key stored in the T2 chip or Secure Enclave, the data is immediately cryptographically erased. The old ways (writing zeroes with dd or a pseudo random data source) are an ineffective use of time and easy to mess up, use the Erase Assistant and tools.
If you don’t care about being secure, you could boot to recovery and reformat the volume. Searching this site, you will see dozens and dozens of people not able to follow that, so I recommended the surefire steps above using the assistant.

The purpose of writing zeroes with dd in my case is not to erase data so that it cannot be restored at all, but rather to screw up the computer so that the fastest way to restore it is to use the backup. That's why I am writing the 1st 128 MB only.

The erase is very fast @Greendrake have you tried it? If you’re not interested in destroying the data or changing the keys, https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/erase-and-reformat-a-storage-device-dskutl14079/mac erase the storage in recovery. You need a second OS to correctly remove the first OS. Recovery gives you that second OS.
